# GIT Tag not on current commit

Tags: git, tags, git-commit

What I want to achieve is to commit changes and tag current commit, for this I did

```
git add <my stuff>

git pull origin master
```

1st Commit

```
git commit -m <message>

git push origin master

git tag -a -f -m <message> <Tag_Name>
```

and then

```
git push origin <Tag_Name>
```

Every thing works fine and commits take place.

But issue is that tag is pushed on a previous commit than that of which I created just before pushing the tag. I can clearly see it in GIT Blit browser and compare the files for the respective commit.

Am I missing something? or how can I manage to synchronize tag with commit?

Comment: Why are you using the `-f` option? Did this tag already exist?

Comment: No, its always a new tag created.